# Menu hover 'roll down' effect CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a certain hover effect on my menu. You can see the effect I want on www.firstborn.com. It basically slides down from the top, but not evenly. I have tried various CSS, and also inspected their code, but just can't get it right. Is it not possible with CSS only? Do I have to install something like with animate.css?

This is the code I use. The ID is the one of my entire menu.

```css
#Top_bar:hover {
-webkit-transition: 0.2s height cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
-moz-transition: 0.2s height cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
transition: 0.2s height cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
background: #000;
color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Your snippet does nothing without the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, basically, you set the height properties on the element. You have to set the inital height, then on hover you have to change that height

```
#Top_bar {
-webkit-transition: 0.2s height cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
-moz-transition: 0.2s height cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
transition: 0.2s height cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
background: #000;
color: #fff;
height: 200px;
}

#Top_bar:hover{
 height: 500px;
}
```